# How can I have Alluxio show all the not-yet-accessed files in the directory?

Tags: amazon-s3, alluxio

When mounted an s3 bucket under alluxio://s3/, the bucket already has objects. However, when I get the directory list (either by `alluxio fs ls` or `ls` the  fuse-mounted directory or on the web ui) i see no files. When I write a new file or read an already existing object via Alluxio, it appears in the dir list. Is there a way I can have Alluxio show all the not-yet-accessed files in the directory? (rather than only showing files after writing or accessing them)

Comment: normally it should show the directory list even without forced metadata loading, however there is a bug by which alluxio do something like "GET //" on S3 instead of "GET /" so AWS does not identify the root "folder" correctly, thus you won't get dir list on the root folder. i may be fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to run `bin/alluxio fs loadMetadata /s3` to force refresh the Alluxio directory. There are other ways to trigger it, checkout “How to Trigger Metadata Sync” section in this latest blog:
https://www.alluxio.io/blog/metadata-synchronization-in-alluxio-design-implementation-and-optimization/